# Inserting into 2D array - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have found several articles about this topic, but I still have a problem. I need 2D array in java script. First index will be number of articles (0...x) and in the second index I need 4 values (keyword, title, description, url). Here is my code

```
var news = new Array;
....
news[newsCount] = new Array;
  for (var i in values){
    var row = values[i];
    var keyword = row[0];
    var title = row[1];
    var description = row[2];    
    var url = row[3];

    news[i][0] = keyword;  
    news[i][1] = title;  
    news[i][2] = description; 
    news[i][3] = url;  

  }
```

In variables keyword, title, description and url is correct data, and I need to get them to the news array. Could someone help me? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set the size of an array with `news[newsCount]` (and you do not need to) 
instead of doing this initialize the first level of the array as you did
and then add the second level in the iteration
with `news[i] = []`

```js
values = [["a1","a2","a3","a4"]]

var news = new Array;
  for (var i in values){
    news[i] = []
    var row = values[i];
    var keyword = row[0];
    var title = row[1];
    var description = row[2];    
    var url = row[3];

    news[i][0] = keyword;  
    news[i][1] = title;  
    news[i][2] = description; 
    news[i][3] = url;  

  } 
  
  console.log(news);
```

note that this will result in the same array.

You can also use plain Objects in JS to add more context to your data structure

```
news[i] = {}
news[i]['keyword'] = keyword;
...
```

Comment: Do you even need to initialize the array size? try running: `var x = []; x[3] = "hi"; console.log(x.length);` this will return 4.

Comment: No you don't, and I'm not doing it @nickzoum

Comment: I know, but the first sentence is a bit misleading. Could you say in your answer that you don't have to set the size of the array, because it doesn't look like OP knew that.

Comment: @nickzoum thank you for the suggestion, I added it to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

why not just use push() to add each news item to the array? like this:

```
news = []
for (i=0;i<values.length; i++){
    var row = values[i].slice(0,4);
    //you dont need these lines, you can use slice instead
    //var keyword = row[0];
    //var title = row[1];
    //var description = row[2];    
    //var url = row[3];
    news.push(row)
  }
```

Comment: Yeah, but then I can't take the keyword or title. If I take row[0][0] it returns only first char.

Comment: Just use row[0] to get the keyword or row[1] for title etc.

Answer (score -1):

I think your problem is that an array is not instantiated, have you tried adding news[i] = [] before the assignments?